# Django logging in file with Gunicorn and Upstart

Tags: django, gunicorn, upstart

I'm trying to get logs from Django app.
in setting.py something like this:

```
   'handlers': {
         'file': {
             'level': 'DEBUG',
             'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
             'filename': 'elections_app/static/e.log',
```

When I running django with gunicorn manually, all work fine, log writed in file.

> /root/elections/venv/bin/gunicorn elections.wsgi:application

But when i trying to use Upstart, to autostart etc., log is not writing. Log files created as they should, i can read them, but they are empty. Django site working as expected, problem only with log files.

Upstart script (CentOs6):

> description "elections django app"
>
> start on runlevel [2345] stop on runlevel [016]
>
> respawn
>
> chdir /root/elections
>
> exec /root/elections/venv/bin/gunicorn elections.wsgi:application --bind XXX:80 --timeout 20000 --log-file /root/gunicorn.log --workers 4

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the process doesn't have permission to write the log file. Make sure the upstart process is allowed to write the log file.